# Google Sheets Search and Sum in two lists

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets question I was hoping someone could help with.

I have a list of about 200 keywords which looks like the ones below:

```
**List 1** 
Italy City trip
Italy Roundtrip
Italy Holiday
Hungary City trip
Czechia City trip
Croatia Montenegro Roundtrip
....
....
```

And I then have another list with jumbled keywords with around 1 million rows. The keywords in this list don't exactly match with the first list. What I need to do is search for the keywords in list 1 (above) in list 2 (below) and sum all corresponding cost values. As you can see in the list below the keywords from list 1 are in the second list but with other keywords around them. For example, I need a formula that will search for "Italy City trip" from list 1, in list 2 and sum the cost when that keyword occurs. In this case, it would be 6 total. Adding the cost of "Italy City trip April" and "Italy City trip June" together.

```
**List 2**                   Cost
Italy City trip April         1
Italy City trip June          5 
Next week Italy Roundtrip     4
Italy Holiday next week       1
Hungary City holiday trip     9
....
....
```

I hope that makes sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "1 millions rows" o_O

Comment: haha i could cut it down

Comment: "Cut it down"! Perish the thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(PROPER(C1:C), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(PROPER(A1:A), 1, 0)))), D1:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: "try" - the understatement of the year.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this one, but it's case sensitive a bit

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var valuesSheet1 = sheet1.getRange(2,1, (sheet1.getLastRow()-1), sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var valuesCol1Sheet1 = valuesSheet1.map(function(r){return r[0]});
  var valuesCol2Sheet1 = valuesSheet1.map(function(r){return r[1]});
  Logger.log(valuesCol2Sheet1);

  var valuesSheet2 = sheet2.getRange(2,1, (sheet2.getLastRow()-1)).getValues();
  var valuesCol1Sheet2 = valuesSheet2.map(function(r){return r[0]});

  for (var i = 0; i<= valuesCol1Sheet2.length-1; i++){
 var price = 0;
 valuesCol1Sheet1.forEach(function(elt,index){
  var position = elt.toLowerCase().indexOf(valuesCol1Sheet2[i].toLowerCase());
     if(position >-1){
  price = price + valuesCol2Sheet1[index];
  }
  });
  sheet2.getRange((i+2),2).setValue(price);
  };
  }
```

Comment: `var valuesSheet2 = sheet2.getRange(2,1, (sheet1.getLastRow()-1))`. Shouldn't this be `var valuesSheet2 = sheet2.getRange(2,1, (sheet2.getLastRow()-1))`

Comment: Yeah my mistake

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot call method "toLowerCase" of undefined.` on `var position = elt.toLowerCase().indexOf(valuesCol1Sheet2[i].toLowerCase());`

Comment: What is the value in your SS1?

Comment: Works fine when `for (var i = 0; i<= valuesCol1Sheet2.length-1; i++){`. Note length minus 1; that was what was causing the hichup. I really like this answer; you've got a single loop whereas mine has two loops;

Comment: Yeah my bad, as I've started to get value from the second row, should remove 1. If i would started by the third, should remove 2... But thanks for the comment, appreciate it!

Comment: As I said I really like the elegance of this script. But when I compared the run times this takes "0.961 seconds", and mine "so5864274503" takes "0.529 seconds". I was surprised, and it is a big difference for an OP that has a million rows to process. ;-)

Comment: Yes and the reason is simple. Each time my script find a match, it push the price into the Sheet. 
For your script, you need to wait the whole 2 loops finished and then add the prices in once.
Why I've choosed this way? It just in case of script crashing, you still have some prices compare to you who can get nothing...
This is more a security choice let's say.

Answer (score 1):

You want to establish whether keywords in one list (List#1) can be found in another list (List#2).

List#2 is 1,000,000 rows long, so I would recommend segmenting the list so that execution times are not exceeded. That's something you will be able to establish by trial and error.

The solution is to use the javascript method `indexOf`.

Paraphrasing from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp): indexOf() returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. If the value is not found, it returns -1. So testing `if (idx !=-1){` will only return List#1 values that were found in List#2. Note: The indexOf() method is case sensitive.

---

```
 function so5864274503() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcname = "source";
  var tgtname = "target";
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcname);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(tgtname);

  // get the source list 
  var sourceLR = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var srcData = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceLR).getValues();

  //get the target list
  var targetLR = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  var tgtlist = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetLR,2).getValues();
  var totalcostvalues = [];

  //  start looping through the keywords (list 1)
  for (var s = 0;s<srcData.length;s++){
    var totalcost = 0;
    var value = srcData[s][0]

    // start looping through the strings (List 2)
    for (var i=0;i<tgtlist.length;i++){
      // set cost to zero
      var cumcost = 0;
      // use indexOf to test if keyword is in the string
      var idx = tgtlist[i][0].indexOf(value);

      // value of -1 = no match, value >-1 indicates posuton in the string where the key word was found      
      if (idx !=-1){
        var cost = tgtlist[i][1]
        cumcost = cumcost + cost;
        totalcost = totalcost+cost
      }

    }//end of loop - list2


    //Logger.log("DEBUG: Summary: "+value+", totalcost = "+totalcost)
    totalcostvalues.push([totalcost])

  }// end of loop - list1

  //Logger.log(totalcostvalues);  //DEBUG
  sourceSheet.getRange(1,2,sourceLR).setValues(totalcostvalues);
}
```